python metaclasses: editing the namespace after `__set_name__` methods have been called?
Suppose we are defining a class with a metaclass.
In the class body, objects are assigned that implement __set_name__ to register themselves in a data structure of the class.
Is it possible to edit the namespace after __set_name__ methods have been run? Like, detach the filled data structure, split it in two, and add the parts under new attributes?
The trouble is that, before calling super().__new__(...) in the metaclass, the data structure is still empty. Afterwards it is filled, but then the class is already created, and its namespace is now a read-only copy of the namespace built up in the metaclass.
Is there any chance of editing the namespace, with __set_name__ methods applied, like via a hook just before it is frozen into the new class?

If you need to change the namespace that will be used for class creation, you're out of luck. __set_name__ fundamentally cannot run before the class is created, because it takes the class as an argument. This would matter for things like __slots__, which have to be set before class creation.
Of course, if all you need to do is mess with the new class's attributes after the fact, you can just go through attribute assignment. It doesn't matter that the class's __dict__ is read-only for that.

Ah yes, I'm silly. We can simply edit the created class after all; it doesn't have to go through the metaclass namespace. We can simply retrieve the attribute, del it, and assign the new attributes. So despite __dict__ being read-only, we can still modify the class, just through another interface.

@mara004: If that's all you need, then yeah, just set attributes. I figured maybe you needed to mess with something that actually has to be set before class creation, like __slots__.

Hmm, unfortunately that's true, we won't be able to use slots like this. What we'd need for that would be a __set_name__-like that does not get the finished class object, but the namespace.

Though it should be fairly easy to work around that by calling super().__new__(...) twice: First create a temporary class, retrieve the namespace, add the slots, and then create and return that, while discarding the temporary class.

@jsbueno: I interpreted the question as being about modifying the namespace that will be used for class creation, rather than just about the much simpler task it ended up being about. You can't modify the namespace that will be used for class creation after __set_name__ methods are called, because the class has to be created first. Manually calling __set_name__ doesn't help with that - you still need to create the class first, and you'll probably just end up with double calls.

@jsbueno: I already edited.

@jsbueno No! user2357112 understood the question far better than you did. The short, cohesive answer and following conversation in the comments was most helpful to get on the right track. Take a step back on your aggressive wording ("plain incorrect", "meaningless", "actively harmful"). None of this is true!

Classes in Python are really dynamic objects.
Very few special attributes are read-only or otherwise restricted, and if you do create a metaclass, in the __new__ method you basically can change anything.
If you have descriptors that use the __set_name__ hook: that attribute is called inside type.__new__ (usually through  super().__new__()) itself, which is the point the namespace provided to the metaclass  __new__ is copied into the final class namespace.
Unfortunatelly, you passed no example of your code - so there is no "fix" I can advise: but you can change a name in the namespace before it is passed to type.__new__, so an attribute __set_name__ will be called with the new, modified named, for example.
And after calling type.__new__(...)  the class is created, but its namespace is not "frozen". You can't change it by using cls.__dict__ - that is readonly, but you can use  getattr, setattr and delattr on the newly created class at will.
Ultimately, one could even temporarily remove from the namespace any attributes having a __set_name__, call super().__new__, and having the created cls at hand, re-insated the attributes set appart and control the call to __set_name__ for each one.
Your question is too vague in what you want to do, otherwise, I could add an example in code. I don't know what steps you mean by "detach the filled data structure, split it in two, and add the parts under new attributes", but I see nothing that can't be done (of course if you really have to "dettach" it, the way to go may even have to resort calling super().__new__ a second time after refining the input namespace with information you got after the first call, but then, just do that),

"but you can change a name in the namespace before it is passed to type.new" this is completely off-point and shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what the question is actually about.

the fundamental part in this answer, as it ends up being the case, is the very first paragraph: in a custom metaclass __new__ method, anything can be changed . As I indicate in the answer text, the question is not clear to start with - and some of the paragraphs tackle the problem trying to catch different possible interpretations of it - I really can't read of the question, as it is formulated, that introspecting the attributes and modifying the namespace before calling super is not a way to achieve whatever you want - because what you want is unclear.

"I really can't read of the question, as it is formulated, that introspecting the attributes and modifying the namespace before calling super is not a way to achieve whatever you want" Read the question carefully: The data structure we want to edit is still empty at that point, due to when and how python invokes __set_name__.
